# Python class members confusion

Tags: php, python, oop

First of all, i come from a java and php background and am now learning python. This may therefore seem like a silly question but it has me a little confused.

As an example in php:

```
class MyClass
{
   private $myMember;

   public function __construct($myMember = null)
   {
       $this->myMember = $myMember;
   }

   public function setMyMember($myMember)
   {
       $this->myMember = $myMember;
   }

   public function getMyMember()
   {
       return $this->myMember;
   }

}
```

This is completely textbook 101 OOP.  A class with a single private member and a getter and setter.

However, learning some python and this isn’t so straightforward it seems.

First off, the constructor isn’t a real constructor (but you can use at such?? )

Secondly, any class level decelerations are treated as static ??  So self.myMember in python actually sets a different variable on the instance which is not the same as the class level myMember?

Lastly, if my confusions are correct - how would the same example above be coded in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you don't use getters and setters in Python; unless you need to transform the value, need side-effects *during* setting or getting, or need to prevent either getting or setting, you just use attributes instead:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, member):
        self.member = member
```

Instance attributes are separate from class attributes; setting attributes on `self` means you are manipulating the instance, attributes on the class (`MyClass.member`) are class attributes and are thus shared amongst instances. This is achieved by using the class as a fallback when looking up attributes; first the instance is queried, then the class of the instance, then the base classes of the class; setting `self.member` means that any `MyClass.member` is no longer visible on the instance.

The `__init__` method is indeed, technically, not a constructor. `self` already exists when `__init__` is called. It is instead an initializer, you set the first values with it. If you need an actual constructor (instance factory) you need to look for the [`__new__` static method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) instead. Note that in PHP, `__construct` is an initializer as well, not a constructor!

For those cases where you *do* have a need to create setters and getters, use the [`property` decorator function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, member):
        self._member = member

    @property
    def member(self):
        return 'Hello {}!'.format(self._member)

    @member.setter
    def member(self, value):
        # Remove "Hello " and "!" from the start and end of any value being set.
        if value.startswith('Hello '):
            value = value.split(None, 1)[1]
        self._member = value.rstrip('!')
```

Demo:

```
>>> m = MyClass('World')
>>> m.member
'Hello World!'
>>> m.member = 'Hello Planet Earth!'
>>> m.member
'Hello Planet Earth!'
>>> m._member
'Planet Earth'
```

Comment: Well, `__init__` is a constructor as much as PHP's `__construct` is a constructor. Whether you agree with the terminology or not, `__new__` is what other languages call a factory (with some language support for calling it conveniently), and is strictly more powerful than what other languages call a constructor (can return different or existing objects). So, OP: Just use `__init__`, period.

Comment: In *every* OO language I have experience with, the block of code that you write to initialise objects and is called a constructor is invoked on an object that already exists. So if Python and PHP constructors "aren't really constructors", then neither are Java or C++ constructors.

Comment: Why would you refer to `__new__` as a static method?  I would tend to think of it as a class method as the first argument is a class ...

Comment: @mgilson Technically `__new__` is a static method. it's even a magical method that becomes a static method without the `staticmethod` decorator, just to be even weirder. It would be more consistent for it to be a class method, but sadly it isn't. Historical accident.

Comment: @Ben -- I suppose I should have actually *read* the data model there.  It's an interesting special case for sure since it behaves more like a class method.  Oh the tangled web that we weave ... :)

Comment: On second thought ... I guess it doesn't really behave like a class method because you often do something like `super().__new__(cls,...)` ...

Answer (score 3):

This would be something like this:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, myMember=None):
        self._myMember = myMember

    @property
    def myMember(self):
        return self._myMember

    @myMember.setter
    def myMember(self, value):
        self._myMember = value
```

Demo:

```
c = MyClass()
c.myMember = 10
print c.myMember
```

And you have:

```
# 10
```

Comment: Double initial underscores would be inappropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

In python, classes create a new namespace.  Barring funny business (like metaclasses), the stuff in the namespace become attributes on the *class*.

```
class Foo(object): #inherit from object in python2.x ... It's a good idea
     class_variable = 3
     __not_really_private_but_sort_of = 7
```

now I've created a class which has 2 attributes.  The first one is "public".  The second one is "private" in the sense that it is prefixed with double underscores which invokes python's name mangling.  In python, this is *rarely used*.  After all, we're all consenting programmers here :).

When you call a *class*, it invokes the `__new__` method (the constructor) and then (if `__new__` returns an instance of that class) it invokes the *initializer* (`__init__`).  Most of the time, you don't need to do anything with `__new__` -- The default `__new__` does a fine job.  Since `__init__` is a regular method, it recieves the instance of the class as the first argument -- Basically filling the role of the `this->` pointer from other languages:

```
class Foo(object):
    member = 4
    other_member = 5
    def __init__(self):
        print "__init__ called!"
        self.member = 3
        print self.member
        print self.other_member
```

One thing that is a little strange about python compared to other languages is the fact that if an instance doesn't have a member, python then looks for the member on the *class* and then on base classes (searching in the method resolution order).  If it doesn't find the member anywhere, then it raises an `AttributeError`.  So, if I instantiate my above class, it will print:

```
__init__ called!
3
5
```

Also note that I can access the class ("static" as you called it) members via the class:

```
print Foo.member
```

or via an instance:

```
print Foo().__class__.member
```

---

As far as how you would write the above PHP in python ... The answer is that you wouldn't.  It would be best to write it like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self,mymember=None):
        self.mymember = mymember
```

There really is no good reason to have a setter whose sole purpose it to set a private member.  If you want the user to have the ability to reset the mymember attribute, then the idiomatic way to do it is to let them have direct access to it rather than forcing them to call a function to do the job.  You can always make `mymember` into a property later (as described in some of the other answers) if you find out that you actually need that functionality.

Comment: `__new__` isn't the constructor, `__init__` absolutely is. `__new__` does something you can't do in Java/C++ (control how the object is allocated). Java/C++ constructors operate on objects that already exist, and provide a hook to initialise the object's state - exactly what `__init__` does.

Comment: @Ben -- Ultimately this boils down to semantics.  `__new__` is the method which is responsible for *constructing* a new object.  It is also the first thing which is called when you go to construct an instance by calling a class.  Because of this, I think of it as the constructor and I think of `__init__` and the "initializer".  I honestly don't care that there isn't a parallel in Java or C++ ... That's my 2 cents of course and I've seen this debate on SO time and again.  Ultimately, it's just semantics and the important thing is understanding how the language works which I hope I've shown...

Comment: Seriously, I think that attitude is harmful to the understanding of new learners (only slightly, but still). Witness the OP's confusion! The term "constructor" has been around for decades, meaning exactly what `__init__` is. If you don't like the standard terminology, just refer to them as `__init__` and `__new__` (unlike C++/Java constructors, in Python they always have the same name, so we don't really need another term). Don't arbitrarily change the terminology and then "explain" that `__init__` isn't a constructor according to criteria by which C++ constructors aren't either.

Comment: @Ben -- I see where you're coming from ... and you have a decent point.  However you *can* do everything in `__new__` and not use `__init__` at all and have a properly constructed object whereas you can't do that with `__init__`.  I think it is important for new users to also see that python is *different* than what they've experienced before.  I've see python called pass-by-reference -- And it is, but python's pass-by-reference looks different than C's because of immutability and the difference in how assignment works.

Comment: Ultimately, python is a different beast than what they came up with decades ago (and it should be ... if languages aren't evolving what's the point?).  Either we need to modify what the old terms mean in the context of our new languages, or we need new terms.  Both approaches have drawbacks, but I prefer the former.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few points you need to know about how Python does object-orientation, if you're coming from Java/PHP.

---

In Python, classes are perfectly ordinary objects too. That means that classes *themselves* can have member variables (we usually just call them attributes). All the names you assign in a class block become attributes of the class itself, not of any of its instances (including the function `def` blocks that create methods; that's all a method is in Python).

Since you typically have one class and many instances, class attributes can serve a similar purpose to static variables in Java classes, but they're not quite the same concept.

Assigning names in the class block *never* creates attributes on the actual intances of the class; the *only* way to create attributes on an object (any object, class or ordinary instance) is to assign them once it exists. So the standard declaration of all the variables that a class' instances have has to live in the `__init__` method in Python, assigning attributes on `self`.

For example:

```
class Foo(object):
    foo = "I am a class attribute"

    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = "I am an instance attribute"
```

Where this often confuses new Python programmers is that attempting to *read* the `foo` attribute from an instance will actually work, and find the class attribute (this is how method invocations find the function they're supposed to call). So it kind of looks like declaring instance attributes in the class block works to a first casual playing around. But there is actually only one attribute `foo`, shared between all instances, which can be very bad if it's a mutable object and you expect that each instance has its own copy.

---

There is no access control in Python, so there's no such thing as a private variable. This is because Python is dynamic enough that you could always get around any such restriction, making them a bit pointless.

Instead, Python programmers tend to rely on documentation and convention to ensure that programmers writing the client code *know* which names are part of the public API and which are implementation details. We then trust that everyone will mostly respect the rules, and those that don't have to deal with their code being things they shouldn't have relied on change.

In any language an attribute with the trivial getter and setter is really "public" anyway; the only possible concern is that you might "one day" want to change the implementation of the getter/setter so that they're no longer trivial without changing your interface. Python can address this problem with properties (basically allow you to make method calls that look like reading or writing to an attribute), so there's absolutely no reason to have getter/setter methods unless there's actually something more going on in them.

So generally if the interface by which you expect client code to manipulate your objects includes reading and writing a field, you simply document that an ordinary attribute is available to be read and written. If you want to be clear that an attribute (or method) is purely for internal use, the usual convention is to start the name with a single underscore. This forces anyone using that name to know that they're accessing an internal name (because they have to type the leading underscore), so you needn't worry that someone will "accidentally" use a private attribute.

---

Regarding constructors, just treat the `__init__` method as `__construct` from PHP and it'll do what you expect (but make sure you remember that Python methods explicitly receive a `self` parameter; no implicit `this`).

There's this myth going around that `__init__` is somehow different from a constructor, so you shouldn't call it one. As far as I can tell the culprit is [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html), which rather bizarrely says:

> It would be tempting but incorrect to call this the constructor of the
>   class. It's tempting, because it looks like a constructor (by
>   convention, `__init__` is the first method defined for the class), acts
>   like one (it's the first piece of code executed in a newly created
>   instance of the class), and even sounds like one (“init” certainly
>   suggests a constructor-ish nature). Incorrect, because the object has
>   already been constructed by the time `__init__` is called, and you
>   already have a valid reference to the new instance of the class.

But "the object has already been constructed by the time `__init__` is called, and you already have a valid reference to the new instance of the class" precisely characterises how traditional constructors work, so I have no idea what point the authors are attempting to make there.

(The official line that the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) appear to take is that `MyClass(arg1, arg2)` is a *constructor expression*; `__init__` and `__new__` are both described as receiving the arguments that were given to the constructor expression, and `__init__` is explicitly referred to as a constructor. Both of these terms are used rarely in the docs; they just say `__init__` most all of the time.)

So I urge you to **ignore** anyone who tries to tell you that `__init__` is not a constructor. You will do much better trying to understand `__init__` by analogy with constructors than by trying to understand what key distinction they're making between whatever `__init__` is and constructors.

---

Putting that all together, the idiomatic translation of your PHP class would be simply the following:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, myMember):
        self.myMember = myMember
```

Comment: I know you posted this years ago but I just stumbled upon this while researching a Python OOP question.  This is very well written.  Thanks for posting it.